# Getting error while display html content on page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I would like to display my website ads on other websites like google ads but I got error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I have used the codeigniter frame work and jquery, it is taking content as variable. Are there any possibilities to solve this issue?

This my Script code:

```js
(window.jQuery || document.write("<script src=\"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js\"><\/script>"))

(function() {
  var x = document.createElement("script");
  x.type = "text/javascript";
  x.async = true;
  x.src = "http" + ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "s" : "") + "://domain/ads/Ads/demo_ad";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(x, s)
})();
```

And My PHP code:

```php
function demo_ad()
    {
        $ad_var = "<a href='http://www.example.com'><div style='position:absolute; width:560px; height:300px; z-index:10000;'><img width='600' height='200' src='http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'></div></a>";
        echo $ad_var;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here do this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function()
    {
        var x = document.createElement("script"); 
        x.type = "text/javascript"; 
        x.async = true; 
        x.src = "http" + ("https:"==document.location.protocol?"s":"") + "://domain/ads/Ads/demo_ad"; 
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(x, s) 
    })();
</script>
```

The PHP:

```
function demo_ad()
{
    $ad_var = "<a href='http://www.aqua.deals'><div><img width='600' height='200' src='http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'></div></a>";
    return $ad_var;
}
```

call to the funtion like this `demo_ad()`

Comment: @mplungjan i just echoed out the html using an echo statement

Comment: What did you change that supposedly made the script work? I do not see where demo_ad() does anything new other than not echo